# Samba Incorrect Disk Usage Reporting

Tags: linux, windows, debian, samba

I am playing around with a fileserver setup. Here are the specs of the system:

```
root@files:/data# uname -a
Linux files 6.1.0-18-amd64 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Debian 6.1.76-1 (2024-02-01) x86_64 GNU/Linux
root@files:/data# smbd --version
Version 4.17.12-Debian
```

I have successfully connected to my shares from a Win11 laptop as well as a separate Linux server. I have also tried using smbclient from both the local fileserver and from the other Linux server. Here are my mixed results:

```
On the fileserver:
root@files:/data# df /data
Filesystem      1K-blocks    Used  Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sdb       1921725720 2273612 1821759996   1% /data

(about 2.2 G used, the CORRECT amount)
```

```
From either smbclient: du command shows correct disk usage:
root@files:/data# smbclient //files/data
Password for [WORKGROUP\root]:
Try "help" to get a list of possible commands.
smb: \> du

                1921725720 blocks of size 1024. 1821759996 blocks available
Total number of bytes: 0
smb: \> exit

( output is identical from other server )
```

```
From the Win11:
Used Space: 102364901376 bytes - 95.3 GB
Free Space: 1865482235904 bytes - 1.69 TB
```

```
From the other Linux Server (mounting the share via mount):
Filesystem            1K-blocks     Used  Available Use% Mounted on
//files/media        1921725720 99965724 1821759996   6% /data

(about 96 G used)
```

Okay, so I read up a bit, did some googling and found that you can use dfree directives in /etc/samba/smb.conf to run a custom script to report the correct numbers. After finangling with that for a while, I got it to run - but, as you can see, these numbers are *after* I have dfree running:

```
( relevant parts of the shares )
[data]
        dfree command = /usr/local/bin/dfree
        guest ok = Yes
        path = /data
        read only = No


[media]
        dfree command = /usr/local/bin/dfree
        guest ok = Yes
        path = /data/Media
```

and here's the contents of my script:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 174 Feb 15 14:24 /usr/local/bin/dfree

#!/bin/sh
echo "$PWD: Total: $(df $PWD | tail -1 | awk '{print $2}'), Avail: $(df $PWD | tail -1 | awk '{print $4}')" >>/tmp/dfree
df "$PWD" | tail -1 | awk '{print $2,$4}'
```

and here's the contents of that log file:

```
root@files:/data# cat /tmp/dfree
Total: 1921725720, Avail: 1821759996
/data/Media: Total: 1921725720, Avail: 1821759996
/data: Total: 1921725720, Avail: 1821759996
/data: Total: 1921725720, Avail: 1821759996
/data: Total: 1921725720, Avail: 1821759996
/data: Total: 1921725720, Avail: 1821759996
/data: Total: 1921725720, Avail: 1821759996
/data: Total: 1921725720, Avail: 1821759996
/data: Total: 1921725720, Avail: 1821759996
/data: Total: 1921725720, Avail: 1821759996
/data: Total: 1921725720, Avail: 1821759996
/data: Total: 1921725720, Avail: 1821759996
/data: Total: 1921725720, Avail: 1821759996
/data: Total: 1921725720, Avail: 1821759996
/data/Media: Total: 1921725720, Avail: 1821759996
/data/Media: Total: 1921725720, Avail: 1821759996
/data/Media: Total: 1921725720, Avail: 1821759996
```

so.. i'm not sure what i'm missing.

Why is the "used" space being reported inconsistently as 95G? Is there a way to report that number correctly?